# Scan QR code and display it along with its value

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I am using Zxing Barcode scanner app to scan bar codes using

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I could get the result in onActivityResult.I want to display the value of QR code and the QR code itself.
I am unable to figure out how can I scan and capture the image of the QR code at the same time.

Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

ZXing doesn't actually take a picture when doing scanning.  It does "capture" the image off the camera feed, but it doesn't persist anything to the SSD card or memory.  You can get at the raw bytes if you're scanning with the IntentIntegrator code they post on their site.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java

You can see the IntentResult has the raw bytes.  I don't exactly know what format it is in, but I bet you can pass it to Bitmap to get the image.